# How to install node-red-contrib-cep for Node-RED on Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, node-red

I am new to both Node-Red as well as Bluemix. I have created a Node-Red running on Bluemix using the Bluemix IoT Platform starter kit.

I have tried to install node-red-contrib-cep using the Manage Palette -> Install but the installation failed with "Failed to install: node-red-contrib-cep Error: Install failed Check the log for more information"

How should I proceed from here?

The log message is pretty generic.

"message": "30 Jul 03:12:59 - [audit] {\"event\":\"nodes.install\",\"module\":\"node-red-contrib-cep\",\"version\":\"0.0.23\",\"error\":\"unexpected_error\",\"message\":\"Error: Install failed\",\"level\":98,\"user\":{\"username\":\"dstaiot1\",\"permissions\":\"*\"},\"path\":\"/nodes\",\"ip\":\"118.189.27.153, 10.84.125.30\",\"timestamp\":1532920379488}

Comment: Have you checked the log? Please update the question with the relevant section of log (logs are accessible via the IBM Cloud console or with the command line tool `cf`)

Comment: The log message is pretty generic "unexpected error":                    
  
"message": "30 Jul 03:12:59 - [audit] {\"event\":\"nodes.install\",\"module\":\"node-red-contrib-cep\",\"version\":\"0.0.23\",\"error\":\"unexpected_error\",\"message\":\"Error: Install failed\",\"level\":98,\"user\":{\"username\":\"dstaiot1\",\"permissions\":\"*\"},\"path\":\"/nodes\",\"ip\":\"118.189.27.153, 10.84.125.30\",\"timestamp\":1532920379488}"

Comment: Edit the question to include the log output

Comment: Maybe it is worth posting (or referencing) also your problem as a new issue on https://github.com/CeZL/node-red-contrib-cep .